# Re-positioning Jquery UI Autocomplete Results Box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using the Jquery UI Autocomplete plugin for a straight forward search term suggestion tool.  It is up and running with no problems except that I cannot move the results box.  I basically need to move it 20 pixels to the left and 4 pixels down.  I have attempted to overwrite the Jquery UI CSS, but have not been able to reposition the box.

Any help from someone experienced with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, tapping into the `open` event and changing the position of the menu when that event occurs:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    appendTo: "#results",
    open: function() {
        var position = $("#results").position(),
            left = position.left, top = position.top;

        $("#results > ul").css({left: left + 20 + "px",
                                top: top + 4 + "px" });

    }
});
```

I'm also using the `appendTo` option to make finding the `ul` that contains the menu easily. You could do it without this option though.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9QmPr/

Comment: When I incorporate this code into the project that I'm working on, I receive a this.menu is undefined error.

Comment: @JP1971: I can't help you unless you post some code. You might want to open up another question for better results.

Comment: what if I want to resize my `<ul>` such that its width is as the same as the width of my `<input>` ?

Comment: Did you try: `$("#results > ul").width($("#results").width());`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I tried your solution and it worked on FF, Chrome and IE8-9 but not on IE7, here's how I did it,

`appendTo: "#results",
    open: function(){
     var position = $("#results").position(),
         left = position.left, top = position.top;
     
       $("#results > ul").css({left: (left + 15) + "px",
                 top: (top + 30) + "px", width: (206) + "px", float: "left"});
    }`

did I do something wrong? I mean the things is, on IE7 my autocomplete results are not located below my #results div unlike on other browsers.

Answer (score 23):

This can be easily achieved via the [`position` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-position), specifically the [`offset` property](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#option-offset):

```
$('#myField').autocomplete({
    source: …,
    position: {
        offset: '20 4' // Shift 20px to the left, 4px down.
    }
});
```

Comment: Hero! I found this AFTER hack the position on open.

Comment: Be sure to look at all the settings available with the position option here http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Answer (score 18):

Something like this would work too

```
open : function(){
        $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").css({top:"+=5",left:"-=2"});
    },
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked for me using 1.12.1 while position property did not work.

Comment: Worked For me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems better to use this options

```
appendTo: "#autocomplete_target_wrapper",
menudocking: {
    menucorner: "right top",
    inputcorner: "right bottom",
    collision: "none"
}
```

Official link
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-menu-docking-position