# Drop the position of a jQuery UI Autcomplete dropdown menu by 20 pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I adjust the position of a UI Autocomplete dropdown menu to lower down by 20 pixels?

I have found one solution that uses the `position()` method to do so.

The solution suggests (found [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951210/2981412)):

```
$('#myField').autocomplete({
    source: …,
    position: {
        offset: '20 4' // Shift 20px to the left, 4px down.
    }
});
```

which tailored for my case would be:

```
$('#myField').autocomplete({
    source: …,
    position: {
        offset: '0 20' // Shift 0px to the left, 20px down.
    }
});
```

However this does nothing for me.

I don't see offset mentioned in the jquery UI docs for position method either:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position

Using **jquery-ui-1.10.3**

See this fiddle:
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv8mn/6/)**

Thanks!

Comment: I'd add some CSS for `ui-autocomplete` (See theming on the docs page you linked). You should be able to set the appropriate offset using `position: relative` or similar

Comment: @Basic  The ui-autocomplete has positioning which is set dynamically with javascript.
top:*px;left:*px;width:8px; etc;
not sure how to adjust the exisitng dynamically set top position down by 20pixels.

Answer (score 1):

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870625/jquery-autocomplete-move-list-position) is an old question.

A [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8jVv/2/) with complex CSS.

But the relevant CSS is:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    margin-top: 40px;
    top: 0px !important;
```